# How can i get the quantity of every product outside of my while loop

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, while-loop

I am fetching data from the database, the id, name and price. But inside the while loop is also a quantity. I dont know how to catch the quantity of every product. The quantity repeats with the new product inside the while loop. But if i want to catch the quantity of all products outside the while loop i only get one value. I hope someone can give me a answer with a post (i am a beginner).

**Here comes the code**

```
  $arr = array();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      extract($row);
          $arr[] = $row;


      $_SESSION['cart-checkout'] = $arr;

      $quantity=$_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'];


      $sub_total=$price*$quantity;


      echo "<div class='cart-row'>";
          echo "<div class='col-md-8'>";

              echo "<div class='product-name m-b-10px'><h4>{$name}</h4> 
             </div>";
              echo $quantity>1 ? "<div>{$quantity} items</div>" : "<div> 
              {$quantity} item</div>";

          echo "</div>";

          echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
              echo "<h4>&#36;" . number_format($price, 2, '.', ',') . " 
              </h4>";
          echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";

      $item_count += $quantity;
      $total+=$sub_total;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are halfway there. You are incrementing inside loop but to get total you need to print out outside loop. Also you need to declare variable total at the beginning.

Try this :

```
  $arr = array();
  $total = 0; //declare variable
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      extract($row);
          $arr[] = $row;


      $_SESSION['cart-checkout'] = $arr;

      $quantity=$_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'];


      $sub_total=$price*$quantity;


      echo "<div class='cart-row'>";
          echo "<div class='col-md-8'>";

              echo "<div class='product-name m-b-10px'><h4>{$name}</h4> 
             </div>";
              echo $quantity>1 ? "<div>{$quantity} items</div>" : "<div> 
              {$quantity} item</div>";

          echo "</div>";

          echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
              echo "<h4>&#36;" . number_format($price, 2, '.', ',') . " 
              </h4>";
          echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";

      $item_count += $quantity;
      $total+=$sub_total;//increment inside loop

  }
echo $total;//print outside loop
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time. But i needed to have the quantity working outside of the loop. I thought i could replace the $total to $quantity and it would work. But i still get the output of one product and not of all of the products. So i want the quantity of every product from the while loop and echo it outside the while loop

Comment: I finally made it work i did add `$quantity_all= '';` above the while loop. Then inside the while loop i did this, `$quantity_all .=$quantity;`, and after the while loop echo the `$quantity_all`.